# esp8266_Lubuntu. /bin/sh: 2: xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc: not found

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, compiling, gcc, sdk

I'm am a very beginner at this area and I have a problem compiling an example from [ESP8266_NONOS_SDK-master](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK). I've been following steps described in **ESP8266 SDK Getting Started Guide** from the [documentation](https://espressif.com/en/support/download/documents?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14). That means that I downloaded virtual box esp8266 image (**ESP8266_lubuntu_20141021.ova**) where all tools as I understood must be set up. But while compiling the example I am getting:

```
/bin/sh: 2: xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc: not found
```

error.

`echo $PATH` returns: `/opt/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/us‌​r/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbi‌​n:/bin:/usr/games:/u‌​sr/local/games:/snap‌​/bin`

and `xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc -v` returns `Configured with ...gcc version 4.8.2 (crosstool-NG 1.20.0)`

The compilation happens under esp8266/Share folder.

Can someone tell me what am I missing and how to get SDK to 'see' xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc?

Comment: It seems that you are missing Xtensa crosstool-NG Please try this method to install it : https://github.com/esp8266/esp8266-wiki/wiki/Toolchain#install-the-xtensa-crosstool-ng-as-local-user

Comment: Indeed, I had to install Xtensa crosstool-NG  at **/opt/espressif** and `chown $username /opt/espressif/ ` in order to compile it. Also in order to compile SDK I had to move SDK folder out of **Share** folder as it has root owner and while compilation throws Permission denied.